AWS lambda how do i pass in my global bundle.pem?
Im trying to write to my documentDB using aws lambda and when trying to connect to the db I need to verify the cert and need to pass in the global bundle.pem into the mongo uri but it cant detect it.
import json
import pymongo
import os

CERTIFICATE_PATH = "/opt/global-bundle.pem"

MONGO_URI = f"mongodb://XXXX.cluster-chs6wio2st92.ap-XXX-X.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=.{CERTIFICATE_PATH}&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false"
DATABASE_NAME = "XX"
COLLECTION_NAME = "XX"

client = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
db = client[DATABASE_NAME]
collection = db[COLLECTION_NAME]

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        trial_data = {
        "trial_id": "1",
        "name": "trial 1",
        "description": "lambda db trial",
    }
    
    result = collection.insert_one(trial_data)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({'message': 'Data inserted successfully', 'inserted_id': str(result.inserted_id)})
    }
except Exception as e:
    return {
        'statusCode': 500,
        'body': json.dumps({'error': str(e)})
    }

I tried using layers and passed it in as a layer and read it from there but it doesnt seem to be able to work i get an error saying however on nosqlbooster it seems to work
[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/global-bundle.pem'
Traceback (most recent call last):


Removing the CERTIFICATE_PATH = "/opt/global-bundle.pem" completely seemed to work i believe no verification required perhaps because it is already throught the amazon vpc and not an external network.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
